# Extracting objects from a list by quantity

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have `ArrayList<Drink> drinks`
The `Drink` class consists of 2 items, `name` and `amount`.

If I have many instances of a `Drink` class populated in `ArrayList<Drink`, for example:

"coke", "30"

"fanta", "10"

"coke", "5"

"sprite", "1"

"coke", "10"

I want now to have only one list, that combines those elements and output to be like this:

"coke", "45"

"fanta", "10"

"sprite", "1"

How can I achieve this. Also I don't know what drinks the list will contain, it may be some other. Just want to combine them by amount and without repetitions?
Thanks.

Comment: "How can I achieve this?" => By writing code.

Comment: what did you tried so far ?

Comment: What have you tried? What problem do you have? What error message do you get? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: I am trying to create a HashSet of drinks where I am going to have only unique drinks. And then for every of them to go trough original list and count amounts. But is there any easier way?

Comment: `Map<Drinks, Integer>` could be preferred collection for your task. Ђорђе, шта то радиш???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using java-8 or later then

```
List<Drink> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Drink("coke", 30));
list.add(new Drink("fanta", 10));
list.add(new Drink("coke", 5));
list.add(new Drink("sprite", 1));
list.add(new Drink("coke", 10));
Map<String, Integer> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Drink::getName, 
                 Collectors.summingInt(Drink::getAmount)));
System.out.println(map);
```

**output**
{sprite=1, coke=45, fanta=10}

```
Collection<Drink> c = 
       list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Drink::getName,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.reducing((Drink a, Drink b) -> {
                   a.setAmount(a.getAmount() + b.getAmount());
                   return a;
            }), Optional::get))).values();
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to convert the map back to list? List<Drink>

Comment: Edited code to get Collection type